# HTML Tables - Cell Spanning

Tags: html, html-table

If I have a table whose column count cannot be determined during the creation of the table, and whose rows may sometimes not contain enough data to fill each column, is there a way to have the last cell in each row auto-size?

I would prefer to not have to use colspan on the last cell in each row, because again, the max number of columns is not predictable when the table is being drawn.

For example:

```
-----------------------------------
NEW ROW | FOO | BAR                | <- last cell should span the length of the table
-----------------------------------
NEW ROW | FOO | BAR | TEST | BLAH  | <- no spanning needed, as it contains the most cols
-----------------------------------
NEW ROW | FOO | BAR | TEST         | <- last cell should span the length of the table
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: In "theory": http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-colspan set colspan to "0" (for all in colgroup)

Comment: What are you doing that makes the number of columns undetermined at table creation?  Are you writing static html or manipulating it with ajax or php or something similar?  I can think of no situation in which the number of columns in an HTML table is truly undetermined at the time of the table's drawing.

Comment: @dbingham:

The HTML is being generated by a windows application, and it would be counter-intuitive to run through the massive amounts of data to find the dataset with the most parameters (which translates into columns), and then run through the data again for outputting purposes.  This is irrelevant, however, as I know how to accomplish this task if the column count is determinable.  I was hoping that there was some table functionality that would account for situations in which it is not.

Comment: Oh I just saw this. Does this mean you can't ever find the max number of elements per row?

Comment: @Alex Mcp:  I can, but with the amount of data being spit out into this local HTML file, it would be highly inefficient.  I would essentially have to load the 100k+ lines of data into memory, loop through and determine the max column count, and then loop through again to do the actual output to the HTML file.  While this will work, I figured I would check and see if I could save the computing power by invoking the power of tables.  I do, of course, have the option of just setting the COLSPAN of the last cell in each row to 99, or something obscure, but I that is ugly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate table for each row and use CSS to set the column widths to control layout. In this case the last cell would have its width set to "auto"

Alternatively if you know the maximum number of columns that you might have (or choose a number in excess of the number of columns that you will ever render), you can set the colspan on the last cell equal to that number minus the number of cells generated for that row.

For example, if you choose 100 as the maximum number of cells you will ever have, your above code would look like this...

```
<TABLE border="1">
   <TR><TD>NEW ROW</TD><TD>FOO</TD><TD COLSPAN="97">BAR</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>NEW ROW</TD><TD>FOO</TD><TD>BAR</TD><TD>TEST</TD><TD COLSPAN="95">BLAH</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>NEW ROW</TD><TD>FOO</TD><TD>BAR</TD><TD COLSPAN="96">TEST</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with DB records that might be blank or something, this pseudocode would get you started:

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $max_elements = 5; //per your example
    $number_of_elements = count($row);
    $colspan = $max_elements - $number_of_elements;
    $i = 0;
    while ($i <= $number_of_elements-2) {
        echo "<td>".$row['$i']."</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "<td colspan='$colspan'>".$row['$number_of_elements-1']."</td>";
}
```

In this untested/unverified PHP, the premise is to count the number of items for each row, and know how many are left (based on a max number, like 5 in your example). Then echo out each item from the query, and for the last one add in the dynamically generated colspan #.

Debugging is left as an exercise to the reader.